# Why do I see my coloring for another object in UV Editing when I should see a grid so I can UV unwrap my cup?

Tags: uv-image-editor

I selected the cup to UV unwrap it and when I clicked UV Editing it displayed a picture of the donuts coloring and not a grid for unwrapping the cup. How do I get the grid back? New to blender. [image]

Comment: You can choose what texture gets displayed in the UV Editing pane. Yours is currently set to "Donut Texture". You can either choose an existing UV grid texture from the dropdown menu, or generate a new one there.

Comment: Oh I see it thanks so much!